# How to play video file in chunks in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption

I want play a encryted video file in media player in decrypted chunks. I do not want decrypt complete file once. Decrypt video file in chunks and play this chunk in media player.

Currently my source code working for this way :

```
public void loadVideo_old(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var context = _listener.EndGetContext(ar);
            _listener.BeginGetContext(loadVideo, null);
            context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
            context.Response.KeepAlive = true;
            context.Response.SendChunked = true;
            byte[] response = DecryptFile(path);
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = response.Length;
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
            context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
       }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
 H
```

Comment: Can you show us the body of DecryptFile? Or is it a library you use?

Comment: I have my code at shared url, Please refer this url. http://pastebin.com/BvqnPFwc